# Django admin. Text does not fit into manytomany field widget

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Inside my django admin, I have a many-to-many field in which I want to fit a string.
[image: The string does not fit inside the field]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: How do you imaging a possible solution to look?

Comment: 1) Horizontal scrollbar
2) Line translation

Comment: Add the appropriate style via a CSS.

Comment: How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a template base_site.html in templates/admin directory with the following content:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %} {{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}

{% endblock %}

{% block extrastyle %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'admin.css' %}">

{% endblock %}
```

After that create css file in your static directory like admin.css with following styles:

```
select > option {
white-space: pre-line;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```